# 2D DFT for lower frequencies only; is there something significantly faster than numpy.fft.fft2 (throwing away high frequencies)?

Tags: python, fourier-transform

I do a lot of 2D discrete FFT in python using `np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(y))`, then throw away 90% *or more* of the array, keeping only the central low-frequency area.

I understand that there's `.rfft2()` for cases where the input is real.

I'm wondering if there are significantly faster ways than numpy's fft to do this, especially if I can specify the low frequency range of interest.

I have heard of [FFTW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFTW) (as [pyFFTW](https://pypi.org/project/pyFFTW/)) and its ability to choose the best algorithm for a given input, but don't know if there's any extra benefit available for a limited frequency ROI.

---

Example of full FT and my ROI:

[image]

[image]

Comment: See a discussion below on "pruned FFTs", where in only a subset of outputs are needed. The author of FFTW concedes that this procedure is not worth it unless you are throwing away at least 99% of your output. Your use case is close, but don't expect huge gains.

https://www.fftw.org/pruned.html

Comment: @CharlieS I see. In my case the time spent *learning how* to implement pruned FFTs will be orders of magnitude larger than any time saved getting the job done with a faster algorithm. I have a hunch that this will turn out to be the best answer to my question, please feel free to post as such.

Comment: @CharlieS though starting from your link and doing some more searching, I do see something called "chirped" or "zoomed" or [Chirp Z-transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp_Z-transform) ([1](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/28535/25659), [2](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/8088/25659), [3](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-set-the-length-of-fft/38885/5)) which seems possibly helpful. My understanding so far (I'm still pre-coffee this morning) is that if you only want to go up to say 1/4 of the maximum frequency, you can use can filter/interpolate/smooth and then sub-sample...

Comment: ... say by [::4, ::4] then apply the same DFT you'd planned on. Of course whether that actually saves computation or human time is an open question. Perhaps more complicated than that, for some techniques there seems to be a frequency shifting transform involved as well.

Comment: [this DPS SE answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/35735/25659) mentions a [Goertzel filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm).

Comment: A DFT is really a matrix-vector multiplication. If you know which frequencies you are interested ahead of time, perhaps you could just form the portion of the DFT matrix (or do the matrix-vector product implicitly without constructing it at all). A naive 1D DFT algorithm can be written in a few lines of code -- in your case you would be limiting the range of the loop to include the frequencies of interest to you. I don't think 2D would be much worse.

Comment: @CharlieS Thanks! Yes that certainly sounds right to me. However, I haven't written *compiled* code in decades, I wouldn't know where to begin, and it would have to be *implemented* well enough to be significantly faster than what's available in numpy and scipy for me to go down that road. However if someone were to propose a working option in numpy.fft.fft2 perhaps the numpy developer community would be interested in incorporating it?

Answer (score 2):

Scipy does have a Zoomed FFT function based on Chirp Z transform, and it does exactly what you need: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.ZoomFFT.html#scipy.signal.ZoomFFT.

I gained 2 orders of magnitude in computation time for image manipulation.

For square images:

```
from scipy.signal import ZoomFFT
def ZoomFFT2D(A, m, fmax):
    n = A.shape[0]
    f = ZoomFFT(n, m = m, fn = [-fmax, fmax])
    FFT = f(A, axis = 0)
    FFT = f(FFT, axis = 1)
    return FFT
```

Then, compute the FFT for a array image of size $m \times m$ on the spatial frequency interval $[-f_{max},+f_{max}]$:

```
ZoomFFT2D(img, fmax = 0.05, m = 100)
```

Bonus, no `fftshift()` needed.

Comment: Interesting! Okay I will give this a try soon.